# Using JQuery Tablesorter to sort Gridview with Textbox elements

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, tablesorter

I am trying to use the jQuery [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) to sort through a gridview of mine. *Most* of the columns in the gridview contain textboxes, some checkboxes, and some regular text.The tablesorter seems to just sort regular text by default. Since I have very little jQuery experience could someone familiar with the tablesorter help me understand what I need to do to get the tablesorter to sort columns with textbox data as well as those with just plain text?

EDIT with Code

```
<script src="../scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("parts_gv").tablesorter({
            textExtraction: function (elem) {
                var $input = $(elem).find("input[type=text]");
                if ($input.length > 0) {
                    return $input.val();
                }
                else {
                    return $(elem).text();
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a [custom text extraction function](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html). It's not difficult:

```
$("table.sortable").tablesorter({ 
  textExtraction: function(elem) {
    var $input = $("input[type=text]", elem);

    return $input.val() || $(elem).text();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried what you suggested and your code makes sense to me. However, it still just flips the grid when I sort columns with textboxes instead of sorting by the data inside them.

Comment: @novacara: Try to add a `console.log()` to see what the extractor function actually returns in your case. Maybe it needs a little extra tweaking for your HTML structure. Setting a breakpoint and stepping through a few cases is also a possibility to see what's going on.

Comment: I put a breakpoint where $input is assigned and doesn't seem to ever hit. Is there something I'm missing I need to do to apply the extractor? I have the correct gridview name in the function. I also know tablesorter itself is working because my grid is flipping.

Comment: @novacara: This is strange. Sure you used the correct case `textExtraction`? Also, does it change sorting behavior when you put some test text in front of the text boxes or replace them with their plain values?

Comment: textExtraction is spelled and cased correctly. I have two columns that are plain text and it sorts those correctly but it did that before I added your code as well. I'm going to update with my whole script section maybe you can see something wrong i can't.

Comment: I just realized like a dolt that you meant "table" literally not "parts_gv" like I had it. The breakpoints are hitting now but its still not working. If I get it figured out I'll mark your answer and if not I'll ask and see if you can help me get it tweaked to work.

Comment: @novacara: I was just going to ask what `$("parts_gv")` would select in your world. ;-) Anyway if you find the error feel free to modify my answer accordingly. I'll accept the edit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5140/discussion-between-novacara-and-tomalak)

Comment: The chat might actually be interesting to anyone who has a problem getting jQuery tablesorter to work with data-bound ASP.NET gridviews.